# Do mobile phones really record in these odd framerates?

Tags: mp4, file-formats, framerate, vegas-pro, mobile

I received several video files for editing that were recorded on a mobile phone. (Samsung S21, if it matters.)

When I brought the files into VEGAS (still using version 15.0 Platinum), it reports some unusual framerates that are approximately standard, including (in fps): 60.015, 59.722, 31.036, 30.058, 30.022, 30.009, 30.007, and 29.919.

The files are in MP4 format, AVC/AAC compression, with standard 1920 × 1080 resolution.

Are the reported framerates legitimate, or is this more likely an error in the way VEGAS calculates and reports framerate? Something else?

For my purposes, I'm sure the difference in framerate will not be noticeable if I disable resampling on these clips and use them in a 60p or 30p project (except maybe for the one at 31.036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most phones record variable frame rate (VFR). Discussion: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4277721

To check, see https://superuser.com/questions/1487401/how-can-i-tell-if-a-video-has-a-variable-frame-rate